# frame-benchmarking::v2 doesn't work for force_origin

Tags: pallet, benchmarking, origin

In `Config` of my pallet I have:

```
type FilteredOrigin: EnsureOriginWithArg<
            Self::RuntimeOrigin,
            SomeEnum,
            Success = Self::AccountId
        >;
```

And there is an extrinsic in my pallet `extrinsic_name` where i do a check `T::FilteredOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)`

Firstly I wrote the bench like this using v1:

```
    extrinsic_name{
        let origin = T::FilteredOrigin::try_successful_origin(&SomeEnum::SomeOption).unwrap();
        // omitted
        let data = Data {...};
    }: _(origin, data)
```

And got the following error: expected associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeOrigin`
found enum `Result<RawOrigin<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>, <T as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeOrigin>`

Then I found a solution in one of the frame's pallets (**<T::RuntimeOrigin>** added):

```
    extrinsic_name{
        let origin = T::FilteredOrigin::try_successful_origin(&SomeEnum::SomeOption).unwrap();
        // omitted
        let data = Data {...};
    }: _<T::RuntimeOrigin>(origin, data)
```

Now I'm trying to use `frame_benchmarking::v2`, I have written the following code and got the same error:

```
#[benchmarks]
mod benchmarks {
    use super::*;

    #[benchmark]
    fn extrinsic_name() {
        let origin = T::FilteredOrigin::try_successful_origin(&SomeEnum::SomeOption).unwrap();
        
        // omitted
        let data = Data {...};

        #[extrinsic_call]
        _(origin, data);
    }
}
```

I guess the solution is described in [the doc](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_benchmarking/v2/index.html#extrinsic_call-and-block), also there is an example of doing similar thing in the [pallet-lottery](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/bc4055bb9fdd02ff4a97d33c6aaae3c635225b22/frame/lottery/src/benchmarking.rs#L90) and I should do this way:

```
#[benchmarks]
mod benchmarks {
    use super::*;

    #[benchmark]
    fn extrinsic_name() {
        let origin = T::FilteredOrigin::try_successful_origin(&SomeEnum::SomeOption).unwrap();
        
        // omitted
        let data = Data {...};

        #[extrinsic_call]
        _(origin as T::RuntimeOrigin, data);
    }
}
```

But compiler complains to this casting. On the other hand this is working in pallet-lottery. Could someone please clarify the problem occured here and point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the source code handy or some reproducible example? It should work as you described in the last block of code. Could be that you are not yet using the version where we fixed that. I tried it locally and it works for me so far.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I am using polkadot-v0.9.40 branch for frame-benchmarking or 4.0.0-dev version as it set in Cargo.lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in [#13845](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13845). It is included in Substrate tag `polkadot-v0.9.42`.

So please update to that version or remain with the `V1` benchmarking.
If you find any more bugs, please report them on GitHub. The `V2` syntax is not stabilized yet.